# Python property not working

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have an object which inherits from ndb.Model (a Google App Engine thing). This object has a property called commentid:

```
class Comment(ndb.Model):
   commentid = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Reading a bunch of articles, they all say this is the way to implement a property:

```
@property
def commentid(self):
   if not self._commentid:
       self._commentid = "1"
   return self._commentid
```

but I get an error saying `Comment object has no attribute _commentid`. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Ok obviously I'm a bit confused here. I come from Objective-C, where if you have a property called `x` then you automatically get a variable called `_x` in your getters and setters. So I thought this is what was happening here in Python too. But apparently I need to manually set a value for the variable with an underscore prefix.

All I want is to implement a getter where I do some checking of the value before returning it. How would I do this?

Comment: you mention authorID just once and it does not appear again.

Comment: @PaulC was supposed to be commentid

Comment: What happens if you change it to `_commentid = ndbStringProperty()` ?

Comment: @Michael0x2a I would get infinite recursion

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you explain what you are trying to achieve. For example, if you are looking for a default value, you can simply use the `default` argument. Something like: `commentid = ndb.StringProperty(default="1")`. Check out the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/propertyclass#Property).

Comment: @PaoloMoretti I just want to implement a custom getter for my attribute `commentid`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implementing a property like that requires you to define the attribute for your object. What you're doing there, is defining a class called Comment but you don't define any attributes for it's objects, you define them for the class itself.

Let me demonstrate with a small example:

```
class ExampleClass:
    name = "Example Object"

a = ExampleClass() # Init new instance of ExampleClass
print(a.name) # a doesn't own an attribute called "name"
print(ExampleClass.name) # --> "Example Object"
```

In the above example, I define class `ExampleClass` and give it a variable `name` with a value `Example Object`. After that, I create an object `a = ExampleClass()`, however it does not get the name attribute, cause the attribute is defined for the class itself, not for it's objects.

To fix this problem, you define the name inside `__init__` -method, which gets called whenever an object of that class is created.

```
class ExampleClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Example Class"

a = ExampleClass() # Init new instance of ExampleClass
print(a.name) # --> "Example Class"
print(ExampleClass.name) # --> ERROR: Exampleclass.name doesn't exist
```

There I define the `ExampleClass` again, but I also define `__init__` method for it. Init method takes only one parameter, `self`, which will be automatically given to the function. It's the object which is being created. Then I set `self.name = "Example Class"`, and since self is the object itself, we set the object's attribute `name`.

## Creating the property

To implement setter and getter for your attribute, you add the following:

```
class ExampleClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Example Class"
    
    @property
    def name(self):
        if not self._name:
            pass #blabla code here
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        #blabla more code
        self._name = value
```

Also, you should edit the `__init__` method to take `name` as a parameter too.

```
def __init__(self, name="Example Object"):
    self.name = name
```

Comment: Wait, how are you accessing here self._name if you haven't manually assigned it in the init method?

Comment: You call `self.name = "Example Class"` in the init, which will automatically call the `@name.setter` function with parameter "Example Class", and inside the setter we set `self._name = "Example Class"`. You could change the init to set `self._name` instead of `self.name`, it depends whether you want to call the setter, or just set the variable.

Comment: If you want your attribute to be a read only, you don't need a setter, you can just leave it out. Instead do `self._name = name` inside your `__init__`-method, and define only getter which returns `self._name`.

Comment: This a great example of how to use a static property in Python. Thanks!

Comment: In Python 2.7, the first example does print "Example Object" twice, there is no error thrown.

Comment: @dotancohen You got it right on that one, I was wondering when will someone notice... However, it's using the static variable of `ExampleClass`, so the attribute is not a part of `self`. Changing it from one instance of `ExampleClass`, changes it for all of the rest.

Comment: No, it seems to be both a static variable and the default for an instance variable. I can still access the "default" value when calling it from the class name.

Comment: Woah, you're right! Seems like there's always something new to learn for everyone. I can't find any reason for it tho, why was it implemented in Python O.o

Answer (score 2):

If you access `self._commentid` directly, it needs to be defined or it'll raise an exception. Since you're instead checking if `_commentid` is defined at all (to give it a default value), I'd use `hasattr`:

```
@property
def commentid(self):
   if not hasattr(self, "_commentid"):
       self._commentid = "1"
   return self._commentid
```

Comment: So Python doesn't give you a _varName automatically with a property?

Comment: @mohabitar: No. You can assign `None` to it in the class though, to make this easier.